# using iframe in prestashop

Tags: php, prestashop

I want use an iframe popup in prestashop. If i include header.php, footer.php the header/footer comes in the iframe; which i dont want. but if i dont include them, it misses some useful functionalities. so how can i solve this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is the problem with prestashop, logic code and smarty code are in the same files.

I guess one possible solution would be to copy header.php and footer.php file and comment $smarty->display lines, and then include your header_frame.php file for example.

This is quite a hack but that's the only solution i see for the moment.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to rewrite header.php and footer.php, you can simply use `content_only` var, take a look at cms.php for example.